# NetworkCommsDotNet , how can I reverse TCP client and server functions in this code?

Tags: c#, tcp, client-server

**EDIT**
With all great functionality that NetworkCommsDotNet offers, it looks like this library is not actively supported anymore. I am changing direction to accept Eser's response as answer. I tested the provided code and it worked. Thanks for your help.

---

Below is my code of simple TCP client-server, based on NetworkCommsDotNet library. The client periodically sends changing positions of an "object" to the server, and the server displays them. This works fine, however, what I want to achieve is exactly the opposite: I want the client to only connect to the server, and once the server detects a connection, then it starts periodically sending some X and Y coordinates back to the client. I could not have this done with NetworkCommsDotNet, any help is appreciated.

**Client:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using NetworkCommsDotNet;
using NetworkCommsDotNet.Connections.TCP;

namespace ObjectPositionClient
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try { 
            var conn = TCPConnection.GetConnection(new ConnectionInfo("127.0.0.1", 50747));

            System.Timers.Timer tmer;
            tmer = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);
            tmer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => TimerElapsed(sender, e, conn);
            tmer.Enabled = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit client.");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            NetworkComms.Shutdown();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException + "\n" + e.Message);
        }

    }

    static public void TimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e, TCPConnection conn)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int X = rnd.Next(1, 101);
        int Y = rnd.Next(1, 51);

        conn.SendObject("Message", "X=" + X + "; Y=" + Y);
    }
  }
}
```

**Server:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using NetworkCommsDotNet;
using NetworkCommsDotNet.Connections;


namespace ObjectPositionServer
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            var con = Connection.StartListening(ConnectionType.TCP, new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 50747));

            NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler<string>("Message", PrintIncomingMessage);

            Console.WriteLine("Server ready. Press any key to shutdown.");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            NetworkComms.Shutdown();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException + "\n" + e.Message);
        }

    }


    private static void PrintIncomingMessage(PacketHeader header, Connection 
     connection, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message + "\n");

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know this `NetworkCommsDotNet` and why you need it. But tcp is a full duplex communication once a connection is established. Which one is server and which one client  is not important anymore.

Comment: By referencing the `NetworkCommsDotNet` library, you are necessarily and drastically restricting the number of people qualified to address your question. However, assuming that library provides a mechanism for you to know when a client connects, you should be able to just move your timer from the client to the server, start the time when the client connects, and it will work exactly as you seem to want. Did you try that? If so, what happened when you did? What _specifically_ are you having trouble with? And if you didn't try that, why not? Did you try _anything_?

Comment: Are you open to non-*NetworkCommsDotNet* solutions?

Comment: Yes I am open to any solution. TCP is not my background, so the reason I chose NetworkCommsDotNet is that it seemed to claim to significantly reduce the amount of code needed for simple TCP tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a TCP based, basic, client/server sample. Whenever a client connects to server, server sends 10 strings to client and then close the connection. I think this is similar to your case.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class TCPTest
{
    public static void StartAll()
    {

        Task.Run(() => StartServer());
        Task.Run(() => StartClient());
    }

    static void StartServer()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12345);
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server Started");
        while (true)
        {
            var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("A new client is connected");
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ServerTask,client);

        }
    }

    static void ServerTask(object o)
    {
        using (var tcpClient = (TcpClient)o)
        {
            var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteLine($"packet #{i + 1}");
                writer.Flush();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Server session ended..");
        }
    }


    static void StartClient()
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect("localhost", 12345);
        var stream = client.GetStream();
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string line = "";
        while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client received: "+ line);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Client detected end of the session");
    }
}
```

Use `TCPTest.StartAll();` to start the test.

You can even *telnet* to this server. `telnet localhost 12345`

**EDIT**

Since you have commented, you want to transfer objects between client and server, I modified to code to show how it can be done (using [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)). This time, server sends 10 *User* objects to client.

I will post it as a new code, in case someone wants to see the minor differences.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class TCPTest
{
    //Sample class to transfer between server and client
    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int  Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { set; get; }
    }


    public static void StartAll()
    {

        Task.Run(() => StartServer());
        Task.Run(() => StartClient());
    }

    static void StartServer()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12345);
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server Started");
        while (true)
        {
            var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("A new client is connected");
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ServerTask, client);

        }
    }

    static void ServerTask(object o)
    {
        using (var tcpClient = (TcpClient)o)
        {
            var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var user = new User() { Name = $"Joe{i}", Id = i , BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10000)}; 
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
                writer.WriteLine(json); 
                writer.Flush();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Server session ended..");
        }
    }


    static void StartClient()
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect("localhost", 12345);

        var stream = client.GetStream();
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string json = "";
        while ((json = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
            Console.WriteLine($"Client received: Name={user.Name} Id={user.Id} BirthDate={user.BirthDate}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Client detected end of the session");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eser, I will definitely give a try. Yes, the other reason I checked NetworkCommsDotNet was that they seem to have ready methods for object transferring and my final goal is to be able to transfer XML objects between server and client. Something like this: NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler<byte[]>("XMLData", (packetHeader, connection, incomingXMLData)

Comment: @user2217057 Are you open to Json to transfer any kind of objects between client and server?

Comment: Do you mean JSON between two windows machines without using browser? I don't consider browsers and the objects are formatted as XML. Thanks.
Sorry, I just checked your edits above in the code, yes, JSON should be fine as well, if two, for example, console applications are communicating via JSON.

Comment: @user2217057 I mean transfering *any objects* between client and server. *Declare a class,instantiate it, fill the properties and send to other end.* Working code is in the answer. I would test it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, of course, JSON should be fine as well, if that works, I would actually prefer JSON vs XML.

Comment: @user2217057 `if that works`? :) I tested it before posting... I think you will need some time to digest all of these things, since your question ended up with a very different code you expected.